# Using old code on new version of Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio

I have a project which was started from 90s in C/C++. Therefore, it contains many old coding styles such as K&R-style function declaration, obsolete function, ...

The project works fine in Visual Studio 2008, but now I want to use it in the new version of Visual Studio (specifically VS 2010) because we have other projects in Visual Studio 2010/2012. I don't want to have too many versions of Visual Studio on my machine.

When I try to compile the old project, Visual Studio throws too many errors.  I can fix all of them but I am scared to edit the source code and I want other people to be able to pen it in the old version of VS too. I want the project to remain backwards compatible with VS.

My question is how to use the old code in Visual Studio 2010/2012 without changing the code. Or if necessary how do I just fix a few lines of code, but make sure it won't cause an error if someone else opens that code in the older version of VS. Is there a way to tell newer Visual Studio versions to use older compiler flags or something like that?

Comment: what sort of errors are you getting?

Comment: As I mention at the early line, it has K&R-style code, then VS doesn't accept it. Some obsolete functions cannot be found. And other errors.

Comment: @TuTran - "and other errors" how do you expect us to help if you are not specific?

Comment: @Ramhound: There are a lot of errors that I don't want to fix each of them. And as I mentioned, I want it backwards compatible. Thus I need a way to bring on VS 2008 environment into VS 2010 rather than fix the code line by line.
The anser of Doc Brown may help me a lot, I'll try it on tomorrow.

Comment: You are aware that K&R declarations were deprecated in the very first C standard, **24 years ago** ?! If you can't fix code in a quarter century, you have serious issues.

Comment: What is K&R-style code? I assume we're not talking about indentation here... Is there a standard document somewhere?

Comment: @iveqy: See the "pre-ISO C style" in this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#K.26R_style

Comment: Thanks. Strange that it doesn't work anymore... however since older versions of vs support standard function declarations I would consider to rewrite the code to ease future development. The function prototype rewite could be done automatic since its so simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best option is IMHO to bite the bullet and install VS 2008 and VS 2012 both on your machine, and then use the V90 platform toolset within VS 2012 (that means, you can edit and debug in VS 2012, but VS will use the old VS 2008 compiler and debugger under the hood).

What you don't get that way, however, is backward compatibility concerning project files. VS 2012 is only backwards comptible to VS 2010, but not to VS 2008. If you need that really, you either have to maintain two versions of your project files (one for VS 2012 and one for VS 2008), or you must stick to VS 2008 as an IDE.

Comment: That means I still have to install VS 2008 on my PC?

Comment: @TuTran: exactly. You may consider to install only the C/C++ part of it.